# How to handle floating point in google datastore query filters?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, floating-point, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I have been working with Google DataStore trying to migrate queries from a SQL Database to DataStore. I am working in Node and attempting to filter on an Entity, within a kind.

This Entity has the following fields.

```
Exchange: String
Threshold: Floating Point Number
Pairing: String
Userid: String
```

I am able to successfully query for the Entities using the Query by Kind functionality of the Google Cloud Platform Web View.

My current code implementation does not seem to return the proper response I would like, though I am able to make requests when I leave out the threshold filter lines. The proper indexes are set up as well.

```
const query = datastore.createQuery('notifications_info')
.filter('exchange', '=', objectToRequest.exchange)
.filter('threshold', '<=', 0)
.filter('threshold', '>', -3)
.filter('pairing', '=', objectToRequest.pairing);
datastore.runQuery(query,function(error, results){
   if(error){
     console.log(error);
   } else if (results){
     console.log(results);
     callback(error, results);
   }
});
```

Object To Request

```
var objectToRequest = {
  exchange: 'gdax',
  time_interval: 60
}
```

Entities in the Data Store

```
| Exchange |  Pairing  |  Threshold  |
|   gdax   |   ethusd  |      -1     |
|   gdax   |   ethusd  |      -1     |
|   gdax   |   ethusd  |    -0.1     |
```

I am able to make successful queries using anything but numbers and floating points. I was hoping someone could point me in the correct direction on how to handle the filters with floating points. GQL does not seem to be an option due to not being supported by Node.

Thanks.

Comment: Turns out it was the 0, if I modified it and turned it to a 0.0001 it ran just fine